# Добавить значение в ассоциативный массив в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var items = {};

$('.shop-one').each(function () {
    var clicks = $(this).find('.add_shop_content');

    if(clicks.data('clicks')){
        var count = $(this).find('input').val();
        var id = $(this).children('input').val();
        items['id'] = id;
        items['count'] = count;

    }
});
```

В данном случае, массив перезаписывает, а как сделать, чтобы он добавил новые значения?

Comment: где в приведенном коде массив? куда должны добавляться значения?

Comment: items с ключами id и count

Comment: Что бы добавлял новые значения, нужно добавлять свойства новые, вы сейчас свойству `id` даете значение id, и свойству `count` count значение.

Comment: `items` - Это объект, в объекте ключи уникальные. Поэтому никак нельзя сделать несколько одинаковых ключей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то вам необходимо сделать `items` не объектом а массивом, который, в последующем, будет вмещать объекты со свойствами `id` и `count`.

Поэтому переписываем `var items = {};` на

```
var items = [];
```

Теперь нам доступны стандартные методы и функции массива в `js` и мы можем при помощи `push` добавить в массив необходимый нам объект со свойствами

```
items.push({id: id, count: count});
```

Ваш код в готовом виде.

```
var items = [];

$('.shop-one').each(function () {
    var clicks = $(this).find('.add_shop_content');    
    if(clicks.data('clicks')) {
        var count = $(this).find('input').val();
        var id = $(this).children('input').val();
        items.push({id: id, count: count});
    };
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: items.push is not a function

почему выдает такую ошибку?

Comment: потому что вы забыли изменить `var items = {}` на `var items = []`, видимо

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, старайся писать более развернутые вопросы, а не просто кидать кусок кода без пояснений, что он делает, и что поменялось.

Comment: Извиняюсь, спасибо, все работает. Нужно будет почитать про объекты и массивы

Comment: ок, подправлю, просто с работы, отвлекли, поэтому просто сухой ответ

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан возможно стоит принять ответ, что бы вопрос не оставался открытым

Comment: @Grundy исправил